# How can I use %r as an equation replacement?

Tags: python

I tried to use `%r` as a replacement for the variable and as an equation as in this code(I probably worded that wrong).

```
s = int(input("How many sweets do you want to share?:"))
p = int(input("How many people will they be divided between?:"))
print("Each person will have %r sweets." % s/p)
print("There will be %r sweets left over" % s%p)
```

And this is my error:

```
File "pye7.py", line 3, in <module>
   print("Each person will have %r sweets.") % s/p
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Operator precedence. Protect with (s/p)

Comment: Try putting some parentheses (% is evaluated before / since it's on the left)

Answer (score 2):

It is a string formatting syntax. Basic usage is to insert values into a string with the %s placeholder. You are trying to insert an expression into string so you need to enclose the equation in parentheses:

```
print("Each person will have %r sweets." %(s/p))
```

Comment: A little explanation of operator precedence and how the brackets help would make this answer considerably better.

Answer (score 0):

Python's operator precedence rules dictate that `%` is evaluated before `/` here (these two operators actually have the same intrinsic precedence, so the leftmost one is evaluated first). That may seem undesirable in this context, where the first argument is a string and the operator is being used for formatting variable values, but the rules were presumably formulated to be least-surprising when the arguments on both sides are numeric. The rules do not then change because of a change of operand type—that would be chaos.

The problem is clearest when considering your second example. Whitespace doesn't change things, so

```
fmt % s%p
```

and

```
fmt%s % p
```

are the same.  Which `%` should be evaluated first?  Python's answer is: the first one on the line.

To fix this, parentheses are the way to go:

```
fmt % (arg)
```

Alternatively, use the more modern `fmt.format( ... )` approach instead of `%`.